# Is it possible to create dynamic types that can be reused in another method?

Tags: typescript

have the following service:

```js
class ExperimentService {
 //...
 public __items: string;

 public uploadExperiments<Payload extends Dictionary<ExperimentItemType[]>>(payload: Payload): asserts this is this & Record<"__items", keyof Payload> {
  // ...
 }

 public getItem<Name extends typeof this.__items>(name: Name) {
  // ...
 }
}

const expirementService: ExperimentService = new ExperimentService();

expirementService.uploadExperiments({ mock: [...] });
expirementService.__items; // type mock

expirement.getItem; // getItem<Name extends string>() string is displayed, but it should be mock
```

is there any possibility to get dynamic types in `getItem` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a type parameter to `ExperimentService` that defaults to `string` (to keep the current behavior) and that you can use when you assert the type of `this` to change all places the type parameter is used:

```
class ExperimentService<K extends string = string> {

    public __items!: K;

    public uploadExperiments<Payload extends Dictionary<ExperimentItemType[]>>(payload: Payload):
        asserts this is ExperimentService<keyof Payload & string> {
        
    }

    public getItem<Name extends K>(name: Name) {
        
    }
}

const expirementService: ExperimentService = new ExperimentService();

expirementService.uploadExperiments({ mock: [""] });
expirementService.__items; // type mock

expirementService.getItem; // Names extends "mock"
```

You could also infer the type base on the type of the instance `getItems` is getting called for, but this involves adding an extra type parameter to the function:

```
class ExperimentService {
    public __items!: string;

    public uploadExperiments<Payload extends Dictionary<ExperimentItemType[]>>(payload: Payload):
        asserts this is this & Record<"__items", keyof Payload> {
    }

    public getItem<TThis extends ExperimentService, Name extends TThis['__items']>(this: TThis, name: Name) {
    }
}

const expirementService: ExperimentService = new ExperimentService();

expirementService.uploadExperiments({ mock: [""] });
expirementService.__items; // type mock

expirementService.getItem("mock");  /// mock
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgY2HA9gOwIYCcQB4AqAfFALxQBKECKWAJrgM7BZxoDmANFEQFCiRQAogA9ILALYQ0wAJLAI4-OGhkmLdjx4IANhgYMhoiBKnAAysYBuiaAG8eUR1DABXAEbbEUAPre488QYAQgAuKDVWNgBuTSdnd08EKBcwbRQMWhExOElpBlwABQwQNIyoCGF5NFoDeCRUTBxcLOMc0zkFJUgAbQBdQkIACjBi0towopL02gBKEIc4pz0GY2ADYAALOANtqE3dgDIKKhp6ACJffwUGM64AawgQFAAzKEmx4ns4gF9Yp1cPF42BBZAECPgtgYKlUaoZsrlzFYbFwAHIYSTlSpSWH4CHbboAckuAQYBP6g32DDCuMhXEwkjCaMkMygXycv1+WnQTExYDgWAUpgsWGsCAgYRaJmkwtFKigaAgAHc4a0ETKbIMZjEeBU+QK1UixQA6FJjSVtPKDWxQcQoBB3MLdM5nXpQb5anWifmC6WGiBG4nXKJQAD0Ib2yhtdruml13oNIpsRuBoIUgzOtvtZy1jjD4czdyAA)

Comment: First version works well but only on the first call to ```uploadExperiments```. 
if after ```expirementService.uploadExperiments({ mock: [""] });``` call ```expirementService.uploadExperiments({ test: [""] });``` and ```ExperimentService<keyof Payload & string>``` change to ```ExperimentService<keyof Payload & string | K>```  then
```expirementService.__items; // type string```

Comment: thanks, i got it
```asserts this is ExperimentService<string extends Items ? keyof Payload & Items : (keyof Payload & string) | Items>```